# The name lookup followed after qualified declarator-id

Tags: c++, static-members, qualified-name

I'm trying to understand what does the following quote mean (3.4.3/3 N3797):

> names following the qualified-id are looked up in the scope of the
>   member’s class or namespace.

```
namespace A
{
    class C
    {
    public:
        static const int a=7;
        static int b;
    };
}

int A::C::b=a; //7
```

The scope of the `static int b;` consist **only** of the declarative region following by the `b`'s point of declaration. Actually:

> The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of
>   the declarative region following the name’s point of declaration, but
>   also of all function bodies, default arguments,
>   exception-specifications, and brace-or-equal-initializers of
>   **non-static data members in that class**

This implies that `static const int a=7;` does not belong to the scope of `static int b;`. Hence the `static const int a=7` cannot be found in the `int A::C::b=a;`.

It is a typo in the Standard or it is my misunderstanding?

Comment: The (potential) scope of name `b` is not the same thing as the class scope associated with `C`.

Comment: It's looks like you're misunderstanding something. The two quotes explain different things.

Answer (score 2):

> This implies that static const int a=7; does not belong to the scope
>   of static int b;. Hence the static const int a=7 cannot be found in
>   the int A::C::b=a;.

No. It implies exactly what you can read there: The potential scope of a name declared in a class **also** contains function bodies etc. of non-static data members. That does not conflict with the quote above that - the declarative region (and the scope) of a static data member still contains the scope of the class it was declared in itself.

You quoted the relevant part yourself:

> names following the qualified-id are looked up in the scope of the
>   member’s class or namespace

Therefore, since in this code-snippet

```
int A::C::b=a;
```

`a` is used after the declarator-id, it is looked up in the class and found.

Answer (score 0):

The quote says "the scope of the member's **class**", not "the scope of the member"; so `a` is looked up in the class scope of `C`.  It can be found there whether or not it's declared after `b`.

Answer (score 0):

The rule you quoted (item 1 of 3.3.7p1) is intended for names used within a class:

```
namespace A
{
    class C
    {
    public:
        int b = a;
        static const int a=7;
    };
}
```

The rule that permits the code you listed is item 5 of that same paragraph:

> 5) The potential scope of a declaration that extends to or past the end of a class definition also extends to the regions deﬁned by its member definitions, even if the members are defined lexically outside the class [...]

There is clearly some overlap between the applicability items 1 and 5 of 3.3.7p1, but that doesn't matter, as they have the same effect where they do overlap.

3.4.3p3 is saying the same as 3.3.7p1 item 5, just with different wording; it clarifies that the type appearing before the *qualified-id* is not part of the "*region defined by [the] member definition*".