# Name resolution for function declared in anonymous struct

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20

Should name resolution work for `A`, `B`, `C` in the following code in parameter list of `f` definition?

```
namespace ns
{
struct A {};
struct S
{
    struct B {};
    struct
    {
        struct C {};
        void f(A, B, C);
    } x;
};
}

#include <type_traits>

void std::type_identity_t<decltype(ns::S::x)>::f(A, B, C) {}

int main()
{
}
```

Actually it [works](https://godbolt.org/z/r3zYhP) in latest `clang`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What part would you like detailed? The `type_identity`'s effect on name lookup?

Comment: Yes. Should it prohibit name resolution on the right side of last `::`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The name lookup followed after qualified declarator-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038003/the-name-lookup-followed-after-qualified-declarator-id) [Name lookup after qualified declarator-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104101/name-lookup-after-qualified-declarator-id)

Comment: I find nothing about alias templates.

Comment: This code works in current GCC too.  Are you asking for a standard quote as to *why* it works?

Comment: Yes. Sadly I cannot put whole question in the title. The question is about the whole construction in the code snippet.

Comment: You have 2 separate questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[basic.lookup.unqual]/8** For the members of a class `X`, a name used ... in the definition of a class member outside of the definition of `X`, following the member's *declarator-id*(24), shall be declared in one of the following ways:
> ...
> (8.2) — shall be a member of class `X` ..., or
> (8.3) — if `X` is a nested class of class `Y` (11.4.10), shall be a member of `Y`,... or
> ...
> (8.5) — if `X` is a member of namespace `N`, or is a nested class of a class that is a member of `N`, ... before the use of the name, in namespace `N` or in one of `N`'s enclosing namespaces.
>
> Footnote 24) That is, an unqualified name that occurs, for instance, in a type in the *parameter-declaration-clause* or in the *noexcept-specifier*.

Here `X` is `decltype(ns::S::x)`, `Y` is `S`, `N` is `ns`. Therefore, `A` is found via (8.5), `B` via (8.3), `C` via (8.2).

Comment: But `std::type_identity_t<decltype(ns::S::x)>` is not a class (`X`). It is a specialization of alias template.

Comment: It's a `using` alias that names a class. It doesn't matter how `X` is referred to - whether by its original name, or typedef, or `using` alias, or `decltype`, or otherwise.